# Full screen in gnome desktop similar to i3-wm?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, fullscreen, i3-wm, presentation

I used tiling window manager and I like two things that is tiling and full screen mode.

By using pop shell in gnome, I got the tiling but I didn't find any resources for full screen such that no panel will be show. I want similar full screen in every app like in i3-wm. Mostly commonly this type of full screen is supported by application like browser, presentation and pdf reader software.

How can I have presentation mode for any app where panel will hide in full screen in gnome similar to i3-wm?

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  Ubuntu doesn't provide Pop Shell so please clarify your question esp. your OS & release details.

Comment: I am using fedora in which i install pop shell through gnome extension

Comment: @SardarBadarSaghir Fedora is off-topic on this site, only Ubuntu is on topic. You now see why: the answer you got is correct for Ubuntu but does not help you, since you're not using Ubuntu. If you need help with a different distro, check out our sister site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The question is more related to gnome desktop environment. As much I know desktop environments are mostly independent of distro. For example you can install gnome desktop on any distro. Fedora is not a main focus here, gnome desktop is.

Comment: Should I post same question over their?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: This isn't a GNOME specific support site (*nor any other desktop either*), but a Ubuntu site that users can login & use with their Ubuntu SSO (*Ubuntu sign on* being an official Ubuntu support site) OR access thru Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the dock (the app launcher panel on the left side of the screen), you can easily enable "auto-hide" in the settings under "appearances".

If you want to hide the panel at the top of the screen, you would have to go hunting for a Gnome Shell Extension that does that. To do that, use the app `gnome-shell-extension-manager`.

Comment: on fedora gnome, does not have any setting related to dock in appearanch. Their are only picture and themes, light and dark